# iTunes Connect: Which screenshots will be shown in store if I don't upload all?

Tags: app-store-connect

What if I only upload iPhone 6 screenshots? Of course the lower sizes will be resized, but what about the iPhone 6 plus? Won't there be any screenshots? Or just iPhone 6 screens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually there will end up some kind of screenshots for your app, but I'd recommend using the 5.5-inch screenshots and check the "Use 5.5-Inch Display" for all other iPhone sizes.

Quoting from the official docs:

> **Screenshot Properties** If your app is the same across device sizes and
>   localizations, you can use the highest resolution screenshot for each
>   device type; this set will scale appropriately for other device sizes
>   when viewed on the App Store in each localization available in iTunes
>   Connect. For example, if your app supports only the iPhone, you can
>   provide 5.5-inch display screenshots and you do not need separate
>   screenshots for the 4.7-inch, 4.0-inch and 3.5-inch displays. If your
>   app supports iPad, a 12.9-Inch Display screenshot is required.

It happened in the past that the store would automatically take 3.5-inch screenshots or just some kind of random screenshots where you have no real control of.